# Optimizing drawing cube with multiple textures

Tags: silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0, monogame, hlsl

I am trying to optimize drawing a cube with 3 different textures. An effect I want to achieve is:

[image]

What I am doing now is drawing cube using three Draw() calls:

```
            graphicsDevice.Textures[0] = cube.frontTexture;
            graphicsDevice
                .DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
                    36, 0, 2);

            graphicsDevice.Textures[0] = cube.backTexture;
            graphicsDevice
                .DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 6, 0,
                    30, 0, 2);

            graphicsDevice.Textures[0] = cube.sideTexture;
            graphicsDevice
                .DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 12, 0,
                    24, 0, 8);
```

Then my texture is processed in pixel shader I sample my texture:

```
texture Texture;
sampler textureSampler  : register(s0) = sampler_state {
    Texture = (Texture);
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};
```

and produce output:

```
return tex2D(textureSampler, texCoord);    // I have my texCoords from vertex shader output
```

Unfortunately in my scene there are hundreds of similar cubes with different textures, as well as other objects and it has bad influence on FPS rate. What I noticed is that I can sample in my pixel shader more than one texture:

```
        graphicsDevice.Textures[0] = cube.frontTexture;
        graphicsDevice.Textures[1] = cube.backTexture;
        graphicsDevice.Textures[2] = cube.sideTexture;
```

Can I somehow stick each texture to proper face of cuboid in my pixel shader, in order to draw it in one Draw() call? I use Silverlight 5.0, but any answers also concerning XNA, or MonoGames will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take all 3 bitmaps that make up the 3 textures and add them to **one big bitmap**.  The result would be **one big texture** or **texture atlas**.  Then you just set the UV for each face to the appropriate parts of the large texture.

In this way, there is only ever one bound texture and no need to perform expensive texture context switches.

It's a common practice.  It's popular too for *sprite sheets*.

Comment: I thought about that, but as I sad I have a lot of cubes like mine with already finished textures. I cannot change them all right now. What I was trying to do is creating one big bitmap using WritableBitmap class in .NET but it has very big problems with memory and I stopped developing that idea.

Comment: @bartosz.baczek If you are going to use shaders then you should not be using textures on the CPU-side due to the serious hindrance to performance.  You should be uploading all your textures to the GPU, and only then at the start of your game.  Avoid uploads every frame.

Comment: @bartosz.baczek There are tools out there that allow you to pack your bitmaps to a sprite sheet and provide you with the UV of each.  Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to it, but as I sad there are hundreds if not thousands of textures right now. It simply to late for me to use your solution. I'd love to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

As @Micky says, it's good practice to use sprite sheets instead of thousands separate textures. In my case I'm want to have separate textures in file system, but few textures in the game, so I write special class to compose small textures in big sprite sheets and recalculate texture coords.

There is lot of code, so I'll better provide a [link to sources](https://bitbucket.org/prostokiriuha/test_voxel_engine/src/7c50f7c79441b0db60d4f71fb342cf244446fd4c/VoxelEngine/TextureComposer.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Textures packing when game starting. If you don't mind about few seconds of processing, you can use it for your sprites.